# freemind not opening in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java

I am a beginner in Ubuntu and mine is Ubuntu 12.04

while trying to run freemind I am getting the message

```
sruthin@sruthin-1015CX:~$ freemind
/usr/bin/freemind: 228: /usr/bin/freemind: /opt/java/32/jre1.6.0_30//bin/java: not found
```

and my Java version is

```
sruthin@sruthin-1015CX:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

please help.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions from this website? http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/FreeMind_on_Linux#Ubuntu_.26_Kubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), Ask Ubuntu is _not_ a place for reporting bugs.  Please visit the FreeMind project page to report your bug.

Comment: @InkBlend This might not be a bug issue, it might be just mis-configuration by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in terminal

`ln -s /usr/bin/java /opt/java/32/jre1.6.0_30/bin/java`

Now, run your program.

Answer (score 0):

You may define the JAVA_HOME variable in the /usr/bin/freemind file, avoiding to change the your java default version.

You may first install Java 8:

```
sudo apt-get-install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Edit /usr/bin/freemind file and add the following line after the first line of the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
```